# Connecting three parallel LED strips to the same power supply

Tags: electrical, led

I have got a shelf like the sketch. Behind it, there's a power outlet. I want to connect three LED strips as well as a power strip to it. Also, since there's not much space behind the shelf, I have to use a slim plug, like the following:

[image]

There are three holes on the back of the shelf, through which the wires can go to connect to the strips. How can I connect the strips and the power strip to the same outlet, while the power strip needs 220v and the strips require less voltage. What kind of connections and adapters do I need to setup this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: sure, just tell us more about the LED lights, like power, voltage

Comment: @Ruskes The type of LED lights is flexible. Could be anything that you suggest.

Comment: Can't answer without knowing the rated power output of the supply and the power draw of the light strings, except by telling you that in the absence of other information you can't assume the power supply can handle more than one string and you should read the specs or ask the manufacturer. It if _could_ handle the load, you'd just hook them in parallel.

Comment: The operating voltage of the LED strips is 12 V and the wattage is ‎18 Watt Hours.

Comment: The diagram seems to show that the lighting strips each plug directly into the power supply, which has three sockets and is presumably intended to power these three strips. power to the power supply comes from the switch, which also connects to the wall wart. So I'm really not sure what the question is...

Answer (score 4):

The **power adapter** for the strips presumably will take an **input** of 220V if that's your local voltage. [many will take 80-277V, or 100-250V, anyways.] That's what you need to supply from the socket, or by plugging that adapter into the power strip. If your bookcase position requires the illustrated "slim adapter" then you pretty much have to size the power strip to allow for the LED adapter to plug into the power strip, while still having enough open sockets for everything else you want.

If each LED strip requires its own power adapter, you need 3 such adapters. If the strips can run from one adapter, you need one such adapter. In either case, you don't *magically* pull lower voltage from the wall, unless *the magic* is ...**A power adapter suited to the job, plugged into 220V.**

The *incredibly poor quality diagram* appears to show a single power adapter feeding some sort of low-voltage 3-way junction box. Why the power adapter goes to the bookcases, and the 3 way box is far from the bookcase and the wire to it loops through the bookcase is a matter of "how to make an incredibly poor drawing" as best I can decipher the intent. Which isn't well, given the poor quality.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your existing socket circuitry is of sufficient amperage to take everything you want to plug into it, you can break this down into two sections.

1. Get a 4-gang extension. Relace the cable supplied in your extension with the cable from the slim plug [I have never seen a skinny plug like that & wouldn't have high hopes of it being particularly DIY-friendly, so do your re-wiring at the 4-gang end, which is relatively simple.]
2. Your lighting PSU can now go in the 4-gang, leaving you the three sockets you required.
   Common LED lighting strips are all essentially electronically equivalent. They are a simple parallel rail with individual blocks of component every couple of inches or so. Whatever they're packaged in, basically the actual functional light strip is taken from a 100m roll of identical repeating components, then stuck inside a long, fancy box.
   So if you need to, you can easily eliminate that over-complex low-voltage socket arrangement.
   You can clip off their distribution box, then either run each existing wired lamp unit back to a single junction box, or if you're good with a soldering iron, run them 'step-fashion' from the end of each unit up to the next. This will depend on how easy your access to the rear of the shelf unit is.

Here's an example. One random piece of LED strip with the cover removed. Once inside the fancy box, these strips are all virtually identical. These are all a very, very simple modular design. Any strip, of any length, is to all intents & purposes electronically equivalent, all wired in parallel [even if the cabling looks like it's in series, it's not; because of the rail structure internally].

[image]

Depending on manufacturer, the plastic plug on the end can be one of many different types [to make you buy all their kit rather than mix & match to suit your design/pocket]. The other end of this is simply soldered to + and - on one end of the actual functional strip.  If you look at the area in the red square, you'll see a line & 4 copper 'dots'. You can cut this strip at any line, then solder to the copper dots.
This means that you can de-solder & replace with any low-voltage cable, of almost any length, in any configuration. You can run into one end of the first strip, then out the other end & to the next strip, or, to use more cable - depending on how well you can route it or hide it, you can run one end of each strip all back to your first junction box, behind the shelving.

Answer (score 2):

This would be two separate projects.

One is for high-voltage and the other one is for low-voltage.

The high voltage (120 or 220) is for your wall plug outlets.

The low-voltage in this case 12 V is supplied from a transformer plugged into the wall.

The transformer can probably handle all three LED lights if its capacity is >60 Watt.

Your drawing would not work as shown.

You need to separate the wiring for the wall plugs and for the LED. The transformer will be plugged in one of the wall outlets and supply power to the LEDs.